# Как можно изменить массив "A", чтобы не изменилась его копия "B"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Как можно изменить "A", чтобы не изменилась "B"?

```
import random

B = random.sample(range(-100,100),8)
A = B


for i in range (8):
    if A[i] < 0:
        A[i] = 0

print(B)
print(A)
```

Comment: https://pyprog.pro/copies_and_views.html

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы у Вас не менялась переменная `B`, сделайте следующее:

```py
A = B.copy()
```

Answer (score 2):

Еще есть такой способ:

```py
A = B[:]
```

Я всегда использовал это. Про `copy()` слышал, но не пользовался.

Comment: Да, по сути это тоже самое. Но всё же путь питона это "явное - лучше, чем не явное", поэтому лично на мой взгляд `.copy()` как явная копия - лучше. )

Answer (score 2):

Ещё один способ скопировать список, с использованием `list`:

```py
A = list(B)
```

Comment: Минус-то за что? за `eval` что ли?

Comment: За эвал. Не нужно так делать ни в каком коде, ни в "настоящем", ни в "не настоящем".

Comment: @insolor, написал, чтобы нигде не использовали. А вообще-то выглядит это, конечно, ужасно, но уезвимостей-то тут нет (или я их не вижу): это всё-таки не `eval(input())`.

Comment: Есть простое правило: не использовать eval, даже если очень хочется, даже если источник строки безопасен. Для вычисления математических выражений есть сторонние безопасные "калькуляторы". Для парсинга литералов в строке есть стандартный безопасный `ast.literal_eval`, но что `eval`, что `literal_eval` - это явный оверкилл для такой простой задачи, как копирование списка. Это больше похоже на забивание гвоздей микроскопом.

Comment: @insolor, согласен, что `eval` - явный признак плохого кода и костылей, но только-вот не понятно: зачем он вообще нужен в языке...

Comment: Вопрос хороший, я предполагаю, что его просто добавить в интерпретируемый язык. Где-то видел упоминание, что namedtuple был реализован через динамическую генерацию кода и выполнение через exec, но на данный момент в исходниках такого кода не вижу, возможно переписали.

Comment: @insolor, ну, может в Python 4 уберут... ;)

Comment: Во втором Питоне `input()` был реализован как `eval(raw_input())`. На вход пользователь мог подавать любые выражения. Сама идея заимствована из раннего BASIC, там тоже ввод пользователя интерпретировался.

Comment: Посмотрел историю изменений. `eval(repr(B))` - это сильно прям )))  Хорошо, что удалил.

Comment: Есть аналогичное решение, чуть более узкое: сериализовать в JSON и восстановить обратно. Сам видел такое в коде.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Ну такое обычно для передачи куда-нибудь используется